How to power on old HP ProLiant ML350 G3 server power supply without motherboard?
I have an HP ProLiant ML350 G3 with two power supplies and 292235-001 backplane connector. I want to use the case with a new motherboard.
The power supply backplane has a 16-pin jack that connects to motherboard. I need to modify it to connect to the new motherboard, which has a 24 pin ATX and 8 pin CPU.
Does anyone have a schematic diagram of this 16-pin jack?
